# Why is my sidebar not appearing when i click on burger div

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, nav

I have build a navigation list in my header class, also inside js file there is a function to toogle another class that will make nav appear and dissapear on click when in mobile view <768px. Cant understand why id does not toogle on click as it is now, cant make it work, please help.

```js
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
    const nav = document.querySelector(".nav__list");

    burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
        nav.classList.toggle(".nav-active");
    });
}

const app = () => {
    navSlide();
}
```

```css
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #fff;
}

.header {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15))), url(../img/hero-img.jpg);
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)), url(../img/hero-img.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}

.nav {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 4rem;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)));
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
}

.nav__list {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 40%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    .nav__list {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .nav__list {
        width: 65%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav__list {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        height: 50vh;
        top: 4rem;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)));
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 42%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
}

.nav__item {
    list-style-type: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav__item {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.nav__link {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.logo {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.burger {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger__line1, .burger__line2, .burger__line3 {
    width: 20px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 3px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .burger {
        display: block;
    }
}

.nav-active {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

````html
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Zakład Kamieniarski - Krzysztof Posiadała</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rokkitt:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <section class="header">

        <nav class="nav">
            <div class="logo">
                <h4>The Nav</h4>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav__list">
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Strona Główna</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">O nas</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Oferta</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Kamień</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="burger">
                <div class="burger__line1"></div>
                <div class="burger__line2"></div>
                <div class="burger__line3"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    

        <div class="MainText">
            <h1 class="Company__name">
                Zakład Kamieniarski
            </h1>
            <h2 class="Company__owner">
                Krzysztof Posiadała
            </h2>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
````

Cant figure out why my js function doesn't work, when i click on burger class .nav-active doesn't toogle.

Please help

Comment: cjl750 is right.  If I were you I would add the eventlistner to the html code, that's how I learned...apples and oranges i suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JS, you are calling `navSlide()` inside of `app`, but nothing is calling the `app` function. If `app()` never gets called, then `navSlide()` never gets called, and if `navSlide()` never gets called, then the event listener never gets added to your burger.

You just need to call `app()`.

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
    const nav = document.querySelector(".nav__list");

    burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
        nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");
    });
}

const app = () => {
    navSlide();
}

app(); // add this
```

As a side note, you should consider turning your burger into a proper `button` element (with `type="button"`). That's more accessible to screen readers and keyboard users.

Comment: hey, thank you for looking into my code! Added app(); to my js file but i'm afraid it still doesn't make it work, any other ideas what could be wrong there? Thanks

Comment: Remove the dot, it's nav.classList.toggle("nav-active"); Suggestion: add transition to .nav__list to cover both ways. + You don't really need const navSlide and const app.

Comment: I edited the answer to remove the dot from the class name. Sorry about the confusion. Before posting this, I turned your code into a snippet and tested that it worked, but all I really looked at was whether I could see the class toggling in the console, not whether it visually worked :)

Comment: That's fine man, without your advice on adding app();  it wouldn't work anyway :) Thanks

Comment: yeah i guess just calling navSlide(); as it is would be enough, also added transition to nav__list  and yea looks much better but on page reload that transition triggers everytime, any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: @DenyDevito you may need to post a separate question about that if you can't figure it out, but if you mean what I think you mean, the solution is probably to set some variable defaulted to true when the page loads, and while that variable is true a class is applied that prevents transitions/animations. The first time the burger is clicked, that variable is set to false (so the class is removed), and then the animation proceeds as usual. The variable remains false for the rest of the time until the page is refreshed.